# Algorithms question on an n*n matrix of distances

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

Suppose I have an n*n matrix of distances between n users. I'd like to know what algorithm to use in order to find a route around the group, beginning at user X and returning to user X, with all other nodes visited once but only once, and using the shortest possible distance in each hop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem is called the Travelling Salesman Problem. There is an excellent [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) on it that should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

This is [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) assuming that you want the total length of the tour to be minimized. NP-Complete, so no poly-time algoritm, but good approximation techniques exist.